# Can i run WCF Workflow Service using WorkflowApplication class?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

im wondering is it possible to load xamlx wcf workflow from file and run it using WorkflowApplication?

Desired result:

```
        using (Stream xaml = File.OpenRead("Service1.xamlx"))
        {
            activity = ActivityXamlServices.Load(xaml);
        }
        var workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(activity);
        workflowApplication.Run();
```

Comment: Why do you need to run a WorkflowService as a WorkflowApplication?

Comment: we have some workflow versioning system in place but WCF router is giving us headache so i wanted to try to build windows service which could load all workflow services in workflow application instances and do some 'hard coded' routing

Comment: Using my second answer tip you can host a WorkflowService in WindowsService, I did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the WorkflowService Root and run it on wfApp

```
var svc = (WorkflowService)XamlServices.Load("c:\\path\\Service1.xamlx");
WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(svc.Body);
wfApp.Run();
```

Still not understanding the reason to run a WorkflowService in a WorkflowApplication. Keep in mind that the inverse(run activity workflow with a receive activity as a WorkflowService) is totally valid.

Answer (score 0):

WorkflowApplication was not made to expose endpoints. Use WorkflowServiceHost instead

```
WorkflowServiceHost host = new WorkflowServiceHost(activityLoadedFromXaml, baseAddress);
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true });
host.AddDefaultEndpoints();

host.Open();
```

Comment: yes, but i want to do the opposite, strip WCF wrapper from WCF worfklow service

Comment: hmm now I understood... what happens when you execute the code in example? Did you tried to extract the WorkflowService Root and run it on wfapp?

Comment: exception is thrown by ActivityXamlServices.Load